Child toys: which production process for kids toy case in small series production
I'm designing an electronic busy board style toy (think rotary encoders, push buttons, toggles, audio jack, LEDs, accelerometer MEMS, ERM vibration motor, ...), of which I want to produce 2-5 units.
The electronics side is easy for me, but I'm struggling with the mechanical bits. I'll need a case that is child safe (which mostly rules out 3D printing, from what I read - after I finished a design in FreeCAD) and can withstand a certain amount of abuse from 1-year-olds. Size should be around 140mm x 100mm x 40mm, and I will need somewhat precise drill holes on one of the large faces for the panel-mount components (±0.5mm or better).
I've considered buying a generic ABS plastic case and drilling manually, but the holes need to be 2.97mm, 7.6mm and 10.3mm in diameter and I doubt that I can produce those sizes with acceptable precision with the standard set of drills I have lying around.
What is the best production process for this application? Cost should be at most 200 USD for five parts.

are you planning to sell these?

Nope, I'm building them only for friends and family.

the components could fit inside Duplo blocks ... the blocks could be glued to a baseplate

Several of the PCB manufacturing houses can make very professional metal panels with precision holes, silkscreen, etc. This gives you the option of drilling extra large holes in the box (a step-drill is great for this) or cutting out most of the box top and leaving enough to support the edges of the front panel.

Image source: Beta-Layout.
The last time I looked (a good few years ago) I thought the prices were reasonable for the quality of the product.

This is essentially ordering just the front panel from an online CNC milling service and screwing or gluing it on the case, right?

That is correct.
